# How to make user to select content language dynamicaly in wagtail template?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-localize

I am using **"wagtail_localize.locales"** for language translation and multi-language support

Wagtail version: wagtail==3.0.3

Using code from official documentation
https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/i18n.html#i18n-basic-example

```
{% for language_code, language_name in LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info for language_code as lang %}

{% language language_code %}
    <a href="{% pageurl page.localized %}" rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ language_code }}">
        {{ lang.name_local }}
    </a>
{% endlanguage %}
{% endfor %}
```

This code is not working

Comment: ERROR:
Invalid block tag on line 58: 'get_language_info', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `get_language_info` tag, you'll need `{% load i18n %}` at the top of your template.